# Meaning of 致命的な矛盾を抱えた

Tags: meaning

The full sentence is: 致命的な矛盾を抱えたまま、穏やかな日々を送ってる。

Checking the dictionary for 致命的 and 矛盾, I only found "fatal" and "contradiction" or "inconsistency", resulting in something like: while there are fatal inconsistencies, we are living peaceful days.

But this doesn't really seem to fit in context (this sentence appeared after a short summary of past events, none of which are really "fatal inconsistencies" or contradictions), so is there something I missed entirely about the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Doesn't English "fatal" also has senses of "fateful", "disastrous", etc.? This  致命的な矛盾 sounds like some major contradiction a society could have, like "slavery and democracy."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

致命的 literally means *fatal* or *deadly*, but it often just means *critical*, *crucial* (e.g. mistake), etc.

For example 致命的な失敗 usually means a "critical mistake" (e.g. in an exam), and it does not necessarily mean a mistake that literally threatens someone's life.

Comment: In my dictionary 致命的 is defined only *fatal*.
I think this is a "fatal" mistake of a dictionary and a stereotyped mistake.

Answer (score 4):

**致命的な** in this phrase means not *fatal* but *unrecoverable* or *unamendable*, which could be said **取{と}り返{かえ}しのつかない** or **修復{しゅうふく}のきかない** in this context.